# Why is constructor not sending array to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have something like this in my **admin.php** controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin') )
    {
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
    $this->load->model('mdl_admin');
    $data['my_test_variable'] = "This is test!";
}

public function index()
{
    $data['header'] = "Home";
    $this->load->view('admin_frontpage', $data);
}
```

And in my view this:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<?php echo $my_test_variable; ?>
```

But only **header** variable is echoed. Even if the $data array that is sent to the view file contains **my_test_variable** too.

Why is that?

What am I doing wrong?

Even if I try e.g.:

```
    $this->data['my_test_variable'] = "This is test!";
```

it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're implicitly creating variables in PHP - which is bad practice. You shouldn't be setting array keys in variables that don't exist. With the proper error reporting settings enabled, this would be causing you problems.

So, first, let's fix that problem:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin')) {
        redirect('admin/login');
    }

    $this->load->model('mdl_admin');

    $data = array();
    $data['my_test_variable'] = "This is test!";
}

public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['header'] = "Home";
    $this->load->view('admin_frontpage', $data);
}
```

And, in doing that, I think you should be able to see your problem now. The `__construct()` and `index()` methods execute with a different stack. What that means is that the variables you declare *inside* of one are not available to the other. What you have to do in order to make this work is utilize an instance variable of the class you are creating, like this:

```
class MyView {
    protected $data = array();

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin')) {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $this->load->model('mdl_admin');
        $this->data['my_test_variable'] = "This is test!";
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->data['header'] = "Home";
        $this->load->view('admin_frontpage', $this->data);
    }
}
```

And now you should get what you're after

Comment: you are right with the arrays and thank you for great answer.

Answer (score 2):

But the `$data` array that is sent to the view does not contain `my_test_variable` too. In the `index()` function, you're not setting that value when sending it to the view.

In `__construct()`, `$data` is a local variable visible only within the `__construct()` function. If you want to access it outside the function, maybe in the `index()` function, one option would be to make it an instance property.

For example, instead of `$data['my_test_variable']`, you could use `$this->data['my_test_variable']`, then, in `index()`, again, instead of `$data`, you could use `$this->data`.

Comment: but it is in the constructor and therefore available for every function

Comment: @Derfder, answer updated. It's not available everywhere. `__construct()` is just a function like any other function, and it has function scope. So all the variables defined in the function scope, stay in the function scope. If you're coming from other languages (like Java), do note that the use of `$this` is mandatory in PHP, if you want to refer to an instance property.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your data with view

```
       function __construct()
      {
           parent::__construct();
            if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin') )
            {
              redirect('admin/login');
            }
           $this->load->model('mdl_admin');

         }

       public function index()
         {
             $data['header'] = "Home";
             $data['my_test_variable'] = "This is test!";
             $this->load->view('admin_frontpage', $data);
         }
```

try this....